# A more efficient way for nested loops

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

Currently, I have a nested loops in python that iterates over lists, but the iterable child list depends on the selected value of parent loop. So, consider this code snippet for the nested loop.

```
my_combinations = []
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
for l1 in list1:
    list2 = my_func1(l1) # Some user defined function which queries through some dataset
    for l2 in list2:
        list3 = my_func2(l1, l2) # Some other user defined function which queries through some dataset
        for l3 in list3:
            my_combinations.append((l1,l2,l3))
```

Is there an efficient way to get all the permissible combinations (as defined by `my_func1` and `my_func2` functions) in the `my_combinations` list as the number of elements in `list1`, `list2` and `list3` runs into 4-5 digits and is clearly inefficient right now?

As a thought process, if I had `list1`, `list2` and `list3` pre-defined before entering the outermost loop, `itertools.product` might have given me the required combinations efficiently. However, I don't think I can use it in this situation.

Comment: you can use map reduce to do this or use list comprehension - https://realpython.com/python-map-function/#using-list-comprehensions

Comment: @JoeFerndz. Thanks for the idea. I think, using a combination of starmap() (because of multiple arguments in func2) and zip() can do the job.